# How to count the number of characters inside <input> tag HTML with JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i'm trying to create a function that count the characters inside a input tag of a signup form.

```js
document.getElementById('username').onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('caratteriRimanentiUsername').innerText = "Caratteri: " + this.value.length + "/30";
};
```

```html
<div class="input-box">
  <span class="details">Username</span>
  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo username">
  <span id="caratteriRimanentiUsername">Caratteri: 0/30</span>
</div>
```

Inside the JS file there are other functions that use `onkeyup` can that be a problem?

[image: Error from Console Browser]

Comment: in my case tested your code, seams to work fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEKBR.png (here I writed "hello world" and give me 11)

Comment: a little suggestion is to use `element.addEventListener("keyup", () => { /* your code */ });`, this can make you use multiple events at the same time.

Comment: This code works fine, check your html, seems like there is no input with id "username" in your setup and JS cant get element by id, so you get error "cannot set onkeyup to null"

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your script after the input element has been created, this can be done by placing your script  after the element or listening for an event such as `onload` to bind your `onkeyup` event.

```
<div class="input-box">
  <span class="details">Username</span>
  <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo username">
  <span id="caratteriRimanentiUsername">Caratteri: 0/30</span>
</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('username').onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('caratteriRimanentiUsername').innerText = "Caratteri: " + this.value.length + "/30";
};
</script>
```

Comment: in this case the script implementation must be made out of the HTML file

Comment: It isn't compulsory just make sure you add the script after the element or run the script after window.onload

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is the correct syntax to add an event listener to a node. Also, make sure the DOM is loaded and parsed before you add the listener.

I think the following code should do what you want (provided that the DOM node exists and has been parsed):

```
const input = document.getElementById('username');
const characterCountDisplay = document.getElementById('caratteriRimanentiUsername')
let inputLength = 0;

input.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    inputLength = event.target.value.length
    characterCountDisplay.textContent = `Caratteri: ${inputLength}/30`
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify your question regarding `.onkeyup`:

It can indeed be a problem if used again on the same element:

`element.onkeyup` will overwrite previously assigned `.onkeyup` (or even inline *element onkeyup=""* event handlers.

`element.addEventListener('keyup', yourFunction)` is usually the preferred way, as it lets you add multiple eventListeners to the same element (and `remove.addEventListener` still lets you remove them if needed) .